# How to capture parts of string into vector

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have the following string:

```
x <- "sim_K1000_human_compact"
```

How can I capture `1000` and `human` and `compact` as a
vector?

I tried this but no avail:

```
> strsplit(base, "sim_K([0-9]+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)")
[[1]]
[1] ""
```

Comment: A little ugly, but `strsplit("sim_K1000_human_compact", 'sim_K|_')[[1]][-1]`

Comment: `strsplit(x, '\\w+[A-Z]|_')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stringr::str_match`:

```
str_match(x, "sim_K([0-9]+)_(\\w+)_(\\w+)")[,-1]
# [1] "1000"    "human"   "compact"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a potential base solution:

```
x <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("sim_K", "", x), "_"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `scan` with `sub`

```
scan(text=sub("^[^_]+_.", "", x), what ="", quiet=TRUE, sep="_")
#[1] "1000"    "human"   "compact"
```